# Remove everything after certain string in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, parsing

```
  A                                         B
 1 www.harborfreight.com/                   www.harborfreight.com
 2 totsy.com                                totsy.com
 3 www.totsy.com/customer/account/login/    www.totsy.com/customer/account/login
 4 www.pandawill.com/                       www.pandawill.com
```

I am trying to reduce the above Column A values to their simplest domain name form by removing  every character after **the first** "/".  It doesn't work on line 3 above using this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("/",A3)),A3,TRIM(LEFT(A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"/","|",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"/",""))))-1)))
```

Obviously my formula above seems to be stripping every character after **the last** "/".  Can you please recommend the correct change?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. your question is better suited for superuser.com

Comment: I wouldn't say this is necessarily off topic here, there are thousands and thousands of successful excel questions here. IMO anything about VBA or cell formulas is probably on topic.

Answer (score 4):

Your formula seems very convoluted to me, is there a reason you are messing with substitutions?

This seemingly works fine for me:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),A1)`

In that it returns the string before the first `/`, or just returns the string if `/` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula.

```
=MID(A1;1;if(ISERR(find("/";A1))=true;"99";find("/";A1)-1))
```

It finds the "/" character and returns text before it. Errorproof.